# I Git Cloned a project into my localhost folder? Now what?

Tags: apache2, php, localhost, github

I have set up an apache2 server - localhost is all running fine and I have Git Cloned the [Simple-PHP-Contact-Form](https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Simple-PHP-Contact-Form) project into my localhost (well `Var/www/html`) folder.

Now the `index.html` folder works, when I head over to localhost. But the folder I downloaded from git has lots of files and I am stuck.

Location of GIT Folder:

[image]

What do I need to access my submit form?

I am a noob in this area, so please provide simple steps.

Comment: What do you mean by accessing your submit form? What project did you clone? Is it [this one](https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Simple-PHP-Contact-Form)? Assuming it's the one above, you should probably go to http://localhost/Simple-PHP-Contact-Form/contact-form/index.php How did you install your server? Did you already install and configure PHP on your server? And did you also configure the SMTP server in PHP (used for sending the mail)?

Answer (score 2):

The git sources include all files to create a docker image including a webserver (which is nginx in this case). These files are not needed if you have a webserver already installed, in your case apache2.

In general, it is not a good idea to clone directly to your /var/www folder, as git always produces some files that should not be accesible through the webserver.

---

What you can do now:

Move the folder 'contact-form' to /var/www/html and remove the git folder.

```
mv /var/www/html/Simple-PHP-Contact-Form/contact-form/ /var/www/html/contact-form/
rm -Rf /var/www/html/Simple-PHP-Contact-Form/
```

Then you can point your browser to http://localhost/contact-form

I'm not sure if it will work out of the box without docker, because the documentation says something about smtp service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! - Since this project I am understanding a lot more around coding/localhost

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to either copy `Simple-PHP-Contact-Form/contact-form/` directory to your root (or wherever you'd like your form to be), or use apache's configuration to direct requests to that subdirectory.